# 2 arrays, adding id of one to another where they have same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 arrays, and both array values have `p_id`, i want to do a check on both arrays where the `p_id` is the same and add array 2 `id` to array 1 using JavaScript.

**Array1** = `[{id:1, p_id:222}, {id:2, p_id:444}];`

**Array2** = `[{id:121, p_id:222}, {id:212, p_id:444}];`

**Expected result:**

**Array1** = `[{id:1, p_id:222, A2_id:121}, {id:2, p_id:444, A2_id:212}];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with using `try catch`:

```js
const a1 = [{id:1, p_id:222}, {id:2, p_id:444}];
const a2 = [{id:121, p_id:222}, {id:212, p_id:444}];
a1.forEach(e => {
  try {
    e.A2_id = a2.find(c => c.p_id === e.p_id).id
  } catch {}
})

console.log(a1);
```

Comment: would this be the same if Array 2 have an objectId as [{_id:objectId("121"), p_id:222}, {_id:objectId("212"), p_id:444}] ref: mongoose. The id( _id in my case) keeps coming back undefined even tho when i log it i see the _id as Array2[0]._id = "121" @marzelin

Comment: @Ylama I'm not sure what you're asking. The code compares `p_id` using `===` so if `p_id` stores an object it must be referentially the same. `id` is just assigned to `A2_id` so it should be the same thing unless there are some proxies or accessors involved.

Comment: yea no thanks man, my one `p_id` was numeric and the other one was String value... amended to `e.A2_id = a2.find(c => "" + c.p_id === "" + e.p_id).id`